# Mover imagens vb6, MSAccess.vba

Tags: visual-basic-6, vba, microsoft-access

Adicionei uma imagem e um Botão  a um formulário, criei este código:

Option Compare Database

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()
Do Until Me.Width < 4000
Let Image1.Left = Image1.Left - 5
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Assim como esta permite mover a imagem do lado direito para esquerdo como fazer para a imagem rodar todo o fomulário,Sem parar com um  botão e sem usar o timer? Alguem tem uma ideia eficaz de como fazer isso?

Comment: alguem tem uma ideia de como fazer isto?

Comment: é a terceira vez que faz uma pergunta sobre como mover imagens no SOPT. Em vez de repetir as perguntas, porque não melhorar a pergunta original, explicar melhor o seu problema?